# Best way to store model image using EF5 and retrieve in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am looking for the best way to store image data in a model and then retrieve it in a view.

At the moment I have:

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a controller

```
public class ProductController
{
  public ActionResult List()
  {
    return View(Repository.GetAll())
  }
  public FileContentResult GetImage(int id)
  {
    Product p = Repository.GetById(id);
    return new FileContentResult(p.Image, "image/jpeg");
  }
}
```

A view...

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
@foreach(var product in Model)
{
  <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Person", new { id = item.Id })" alt="Person Image" />
}
```

What happens is as I get more and more products in the list, the images start to flash up on the screen as appose to loading instantly.

I am publishing to Azure so I can't really just go change `byte[]` to `string` and make string look in `~/Images/ProductImage.jpeg` as I will have to publish the website every time I want to add a new product (as far as I am aware).

I am just looking for an alternative method of doing this or a reason why the images on my view appear gradually and flash up one after the other instead of instantly?

Comment: Would it make more sense to store your images in a folder on the server, then in your `Product` would store the relative path to the image, rather than the image itself.

Comment: @gunr2171 as I mentioned, I am deploying to azure so I am not directly sure how I would go about this without deploying the site every time?

Comment: Do you have the ability to read/write to a folder from your website?

Comment: @gunr2171 as I have just said... The website is hosted on Azure **not** a server. There aren't any folders exposed as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images "flash" up instead of instantaneously because your browser has to return to the server for each image. Many browsers have a limit on how many extra links (css files, js files, image files, etc.) that it can have open at any given time.  So that's why your images don't appear instantaneously.

Some things you can do to help:

- If your images don't change often, add an `[OutputCache(...)]` attribute to your `GetImage` action.  This way, the images will cache on the server and/or on the client for faster loading.
- Store your files locally on the server instead of in a database.  This will let your IIS access the files directly as static files and avoid the MVC pipeline.
- Keep your files in the database, but cache them on your server (for example, under App_Data) as you retrieve them from the database.  This avoids a database access.

**Edit:**

- Store the image files in a publicly accessible (or semi-publicly) Azure blob.  Your `img` src tags would point directly to the blob for access.

Comment: With the second point, I am on `Azure` not `IIS` - I will try the `OutputCache` attribute :)

Comment: Can you store the images in a publicly accessible Azure blob?  That way the browser goes directly to Azure for the image and bypasses your app completely.

Comment: That is one avenue I am exploring also, was just going to see if somebody recommended it before looking into it as it is yet another learning curve :)

Answer (score 1):

One of way of doing this would be to display the image directly from the byte array:

```
<img src="data:image/png; base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(product.Image)">
```

Should work for small images. You may also wish to store the image MIME so you can differentiate between data/png and data/jpg etc.

This should load the images immediately, as they will be part of the model sent to the view.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that the page will be larger to download.  The image data will also be bigger because of the base64 encoding).